# Having trouble removing a class at the right time in a script

Tags: jquery

I'm making a media wall where there's a grid of four squares, and when you click one of the squares it expands and covers the adjacent square (two wide). I'm doing this by applying an absolute class to the adjacent square and then expanding the clicked square taking it in front of its adjacent sibling.

The issue I have is that when you click an unopened square (sq2) while there's a square already open (sq1), sq1 closes sq2 opens but the square adjacent to sq1 still has the absolute class on it, so you cant click the tile.

I've tried positioning the remove class .behind in a variety of places but I can't seem to get it right.

If anyone can shed any light on this I'd appreciate it.
Thanks in advance for any help and suggestions.

Here's the pen: http://codepen.io/number8pie/pen/rLOQZq

HTML

```
<section class="box-wrap">
  <div class="box blue-mid">
    <i class="close"></i>
    <div class="content"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="box blue-light">
    <i class="close"></i>
    <div class="content"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="box blue-light">
    <i class="close"></i>
    <div class="content"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="box blue-mid">
    <i class="close"></i>
    <div class="content"></div>
  </div>
</section>
```

CSS

```
.blue-light {
  background-color: #b3e6ff;
}

.blue-mid {
  background-color: #66ccff;
}

.box-wrap {
  width: 600px;
  height: 600px;

  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  position: relative;
}

.box {
  position: relative;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;

  z-index: 1;
}

.box:nth-child(2),
.box:nth-child(4) {
  margin-left: auto;
}

.behind {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -10;
}

.close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  padding: 8px;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #cc0000;
}
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".box-wrap > .box").click(function(event) {
    // Set up DOM variables
    $this = $(this);
    $siblings = $(this).siblings(".box");

    var fullWidth = $(".box-wrap").width();
    var halfWidth = ($(".box-wrap").width() / 2);

    if ($this.hasClass("active")) {
      $this.animate({
          width: halfWidth
        },
        500,
        function() {
          $this.removeClass("active");
          $siblings.removeClass("behind");
          $this.children(".close").removeClass("fa fa-close");
        });
    } else {
      // remove all active classes from other elements and set to halfWidth
      $siblings.animate({
          width: halfWidth
        },
        500,
        function() {
          $siblings.removeClass("active");
          $siblings.children(".close").removeClass("fa fa-close");
        });

      // find out what child this element is
      var index = $this.index();

      switch (parseInt(index)) {
        case 0:
          $siblings.eq(0).addClass("behind").css({
            top: '0',
            right: '0'
          });
          break;
        case 1:
          $siblings.eq(0).addClass("behind").css({
            top: '0',
            left: '0'
          });
          break;
        case 2:
          $siblings.eq(2).addClass("behind").css({
            bottom: '0',
            right: '0'
          });
          break;
        case 3:
          $siblings.eq(2).addClass("behind").css({
            bottom: '0',
            left: '0'
          });
          break;
      }

      $this.animate({
          width: fullWidth
        },
        500,
        function() {
          $this.addClass("active");
          $this.children(".close").addClass("fa fa-close");
        });
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty nice idea you got !

[Here is the Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/b63q14Lc/1/)

Btw I changed a bit your jQuery to some CSS style that can achieve the same thing. You can change the animation style (currently all ease) of the tiles and the duration to some fancy effect !

HTML :

```
 <section class="box-wrap">
  <div class="box boxTopLeft blue-mid">
    <i class="close"></i>
    <div class="content"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="box boxTopRight blue-light">
    <i class="close"></i>
    <div class="content"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="box boxBotLeft blue-light">
    <i class="close"></i>
    <div class="content"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="box boxBotRight blue-mid">
    <i class="close"></i>
    <div class="content"></div>
  </div>
</section>
```

As you only got 4 squares and you don't have to create more tiles, you can set it up in CSS this way :

```
.blue-light {
  background-color: #b3e6ff;
}

.blue-mid {
  background-color: #66ccff;
}

.box-wrap {
  width: 600px;
  height: 600px;
  position: relative;
}

.box {
  position: absolute;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  transition: all 1s ease;
  z-index: 1;
}

.boxTopLeft {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.boxTopRight {
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
}

.boxBotLeft {
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.boxBotRight {
  bottom: 0;
  left: 50%;
}

.boxTopRight.active {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.boxBotRight.active {
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.box.active {
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 10;
}
```

And a bit of jQuery :

```
$(function() {

  $('.box').click(function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass('active'))
      $(this).removeClass('active');
    else {
      $('.box').removeClass('active');
      $(this).addClass('active');
    }
  });

});
```

Here you go !

Comment: Thanks! I'll try this out and get back to you. I thought my jQuery was getting a bit verbose for what I was trying to do, but I'm quite new to JS so I'm tending to throw the kitchen sink at a problem!